# How can I obtain a memory address for another C# app to read?

Tags: c#

I want to use 2 C# apps to communicate to each other by memory. For the host side I used:

```
int* ptr = &level;
```

And for the client side I want to use:

```
ReadProcessMemory((int)_handle, <returned result of int* ptr>, _buffer, 2, ref bytesRead);
```

But the ReadProcessMemory doesn't work. For example: level set to 3 but ReadProcessMemory returns 0. What the hell out of this? (NOTE: "level" field is not cleared from memory)

I tried int* ptr lots of times because lots of websites tell me to do that but that doesn't work so well with ReadProcessMemory.

I set level = 3 but the result of ReadProcessMemory of level = 0

Comment: C#? ReadProcessMemory? Are you referring to the Win32 function? You should not be using the Win32 api for this kind of process, there are other mechanisms already in the .net framework to do this... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Is there any reason you're attempting to use shared memory rather than some other form of inter-process communication(IPC)?     I would recommend looking into other forms of communication if possible.  (For example: https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ )

Comment: I don't know how to get primary (never changes) address in C#

Comment: You can force an object to never change position using a gc handle. **BUT DO NOT DO THIS**. This is a very, very wrong way to do interprocess communications in C#.

Answer (score 3):

What you ask, in the way you ask is pretty much dangerous as the process is entirely managed by the CLR. Depending what you want to share and how, you could consider sockets or pipes. 
Alternatively, you could use interop, but it requires a certain expertise and tinkering in my opinion.

The cleanest way for two C# applications to communicate via memory is by use memory mapped files. Messing with the memory in a managed process can get subtle issues. Memory mapped files are a way to share information.

Keep in mind that each memory mapped file is loaded at different memory addresses, therefore you need to structure it without the use of absolute pointers.

Edit:
Direct raw memory access requires knowing the exact physical address to access as the virtual addresses allocated in the target process are different and possibly overlapping with those of the source process. C# applications are hosted by the Common Language Runtime which is in control of everything, including memory allocation. In particular, a standard c# application di not manage a bit of its own memory: as the runtime moves the objects as part of the normal application lifetime, such addresses change over time.

If you are in control of the target application, you can pin the object via the `GC` class to forbid movements, then you have to take the address of the object, and pass it to the other process. The other process must then open the target process for reading, mapping the memory segments, calculate the location of the memory to read by translating the virtual address.

What you ask requires cooperating processes and a lot of low level knowledge, and in the end, you also might never be able to read updated memory changes, as the CLR might not write back the values to memory (have a look to `volatile` for this).

It is clearing exciting to write such software, but when you are in control of both the applications, there are cleaner and much more reliable ways to achieve your goal.

As a side note, this technique is used by trainers, hacker tools and viruses, therfore antivirus softwares will raise red flags when they see such behavior.

Comment: I don't want to use memory files or pipes. I would mean, get the primary (never changes) memory address of a variable. How can I force to do that because & changes over time.

Comment: I have updated the answer, as I would overflow the comment length. Hope it helps.

Comment: For an example of how to use a memory mapped file, Microsoft has provided a code sample, [Use shared memory for IPC in C#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSFileMappingClient-50e7ebc1).  Personally, I prefer the [NetNamedPipeBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/netnamedpipebinding) approach, since it provides type safety.  However, I acknowledge that the approach you describe is closer to what OP is requesting.